# Can portions of the Func<T1,T2,....> parameter be given xml comments for intellisense?

Tags: c#, delegates, comments, xml-comments

So, I have a an action that takes a callback and performs it. It looks a little bit like this. Is there anything I can fill in into the question mark area (or elsewhere) to document the details of the arguments going into the APICall Func parameter?

```
/// <summary>
/// Opens Authenticated session to servers using ClientSide SDK's, performs action, closes session
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The object to be returned from the authenticated action</typeparam>
/// <param name="credentials">Container for username, password</param>
/// <param name="APICall">?????????????????</param>
///
/// ?????????????????????
/// ?????????????????????
/// ?????????????????????
///    
/// <returns>T</returns>
private static T MakeAuthenticatedCall<T> (CredStorage Credentials, Func<string,T> APICALL)
{
   AuthenticationManager.Login(Credentials);
   T APIResult = APICall(AuthenticationManager.SessionID);
   AuthenticationManager.LogOff();

   return APIResult;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Can't you just put it between the <param name="APICall">?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck I don't think so. I'm looking to describe the "string" and "T" portions of "Func<string,T> APICALL", and don't see any obvious XML bits that would describe them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your own delegate to do this, rather than use the built-in `Func<T,...>` delegate.

Then not only can you give it XML documentation, you can give a more descriptive name to the parameters.

For example:

```
/// <summary>Makes an API call.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type returned by the API call.</typeparam>
/// <param name="param">The parameter passed to the API call.</param>
/// <returns>The value returned by the API call.</returns>

public delegate T ApiCall<T>(string param);
```

Then you would use that instead of `Func<string,T>` in your method:

```
private static T MakeAuthenticatedCall<T>(CredStorage Credentials, ApiCall<T> APICALL)
{
```

This is arguably a much better way of doing it, although at the expense of having to take the extra time to define a special delegate.